# Manipulating strings in Ruby with '+' and 'insert'

Tags: ruby, variables

I have the following Ruby code:

```
a = "Python"
b = a.+"xyz"
c = b.insert(2, "oo")
puts a
puts b
puts c
```

I was expecting :

```
Python
Pythonxyz
Pyoothonxyz
```

but I get:

```
Python
Pyoothonxyz
Pyoothonxyz
```

Anybody can help me ? I have just started with Ruby and this is a bit puzzling. Thxs for the help.

Comment: The `insert` function is changing original string. That's the way it works, usually in Ruby if you wan't to change original object you need to add `!` to the method but `insert` acts as it had one by default.

Comment: You get the expected result duplicating `b`: `c = b.dup.insert(2, "oo")`, see @Jörg W Mittag answer here below.

Comment: Thanks to you both -- very valuable insight

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 'Python'
b = a + 'xyz'
```

As [the documentation says](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B), `String#+` returns a *new* string that is the concatenation of the receiver and the argument (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `str + other_str` → `new_str`
>
> Concatenation—**Returns a new String** containing `other_str` concatenated to `str`.

So, `a` and `b` reference *different* strings.

```
c = b.insert(2, 'oo')
```

As [the documentation says](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-insert), `String#insert` *modifies* the string, so the string is still the same one, just with different content (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `insert(index, other_str)` → `str`
>
> Inserts `other_str` before the character at the given `index`, **modifying `str`**. […]

So, `b` and `c` reference *the same* string.

In other words, there are in total *two* strings in your code. One is referenced by `a` and the other is referenced by both `b` and `c`.